# Font color issue while designing the application

Tags: c#

I have an issue in the font color design in c# while creating pdf text write,getting font size,color and stored in properties. Here, I need to write functionality and to know how should I pass a color as input variables to get the output. If I write kavin about creating pdf along with font input parameters, it should behave based on given font size label and color.

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, Convert.ToInt32(properties.PageLeft), Convert.ToInt32(properties.PageRight), Convert.ToInt32(properties.PageTop), Convert.ToInt32(properties.PageBottom) );
PdfWriter write = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(properties.PdfPath, FileMode.Create)); 
doc.Open(); 
Font font = FontFactory.GetFont(properties.Font, Convert.ToInt32(properties.FontSize)); 
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(properties.Text); 
doc.Add(paragraph); 
doc.Close(); //This is the code except color
```

Comment: Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, Convert.ToInt32(properties.PageLeft),
                 Convert.ToInt32(properties.PageRight), Convert.ToInt32(properties.PageTop),
                 Convert.ToInt32(properties.PageBottom) );
PdfWriter write = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(properties.PdfPath, FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();
Font font = FontFactory.GetFont(properties.Font, Convert.ToInt32(properties.FontSize));
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(properties.Text);
doc.Add(paragraph);
doc.Close();   //This is the code except color

Comment: Hi Kavin, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please tell us more about what is the problem exactly with your code? What is happening vs. what you expect to happen?

Comment: Be careful when editing. You undid a kind and helpful edit of somebody else.

Comment: I am doing simple application of create pdf...In color text box,i need to display one specific color from multiple colors options.(ex:Text as kavin ,i display this text in blue color and select that color from mulitple color option) but the color which am getting as argb format,so how should i pass this argb format to my pdf create function code.

Answer (score 0):

Hi kavin In future do try to add what libraries you are working with, This will simply thing's for us.

Under the context of your code I believe your using IText.

I think your not sharing your variable listings as well which complicates this.

```cs
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, Convert.ToInt32(properties.PageLeft), Convert.ToInt32(properties.PageRight), Convert.ToInt32(properties.PageTop), Convert.ToInt32(properties.PageBottom) );
PdfWriter write = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(properties.PdfPath, FileMode.Create)); 
doc.Open(); 
Font font = FontFactory.GetFont("What font you want", "Font size" , "Color.RED"); 
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(properties.Text); 
doc.Add(paragraph); 
doc.Close(); //This is the code except color 


Font font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", "28" , Color.RED); //A more specific Example

//If this doesnt work try and use:

paragraph.setColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
```

Please do let me know if this doesn't work, And i'll do my best to assist you further.

Comment: If this helped you please dont forget to mark the answer as correct